# How to tag questions about working with source code in a particular language?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, [Folding fails: vim can't find any fold](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/534/folding-fails-vim-cant-find-any-fold) is tagged with [folding](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folding) [php](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php).

Should we have specific tags for questions about editing source code in a particular programming language?

Please vote for one of the proposals below or add a counterproposal of your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, but *only* if the question is specific to a specific filetype, or occurs only with a specific filetype.

Vim ships with a number of support files for many different formats (not just programming languages), for PHP:

```
$ find /usr/share/vim -name php\*
/usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload/phpcomplete.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/php.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/php.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/php.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/compiler/php.vim
```

In your example, the question was specifically about a problem that is specific to the PHP filetype, so the [php](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) tag is useful. People experienced with using Vim to edit PHP could follow this tag, and answer questions about it.

An example where the tag would *not* be useful might be a question such as
[How to comment out a set of lines which are selected in visual mode?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/130/how-to-comment-out-a-set-of-lines-which-are-selected-in-visual-mode?s=2|0.4591)
or 
[Using % in languages without curly braces](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/126/using-in-languages-without-curly-braces)
where a code example is provided in PHP. This question is not about the PHP filetype *as such*.

As for the tagging, we could use prefix them with `filetype-`; eg. [filetype-python](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filetype-python); this would clarify that the question is about the python filetype. There are also filetypes about other things that might cause confusion, such as [xxd](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xxd) and [filetype-xxd](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filetype-xxd) or [help](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help) and [filetype-help](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filetype-help).

I think using [vimscript-python](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vimscript-python) instead of just [python](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) would also be a good idea, as this makes it clearer what the tag is about, and would probably reduce the number of questions that *should* have been tagged with [filetype-python](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filetype-python) but are tagged with [python](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such tags help organize the site.  It recognizes that there are concerns that are specific to each programming language.  As another example, [How do I move vertically until reaching a non-whitespace character?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/120/24) addresses a concern when working with Ruby code.

However, it would be better to use a naming convention like [ide-php](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ide-php).  Otherwise, it would be unclear whether a [python] tag refers to a question about scripting Vim using Python ([vimscript-python](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vimscript-python)) or editing Python source code.

Comment: No, I don't quite agree. There's zillions of 2D languages, why would this particular question need a tag of any single of them?

Answer (score -1):

No, a generic [ide](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ide) tag suffices.  Tags about the content of the source code being edited would be too troublesome.  For example, for the purposes of configuring folding, PHP isn't that different from C or Java.  So why limit the question by putting a [PHP] tag on it?

Trying to categorize all of the programming languages into a few language families that everyone can agree on is a hopeless task, so it's better to just rely on title and body text searches.